# Python: Trying to execute command to clear screen if user inputs certain number

Tags: python

I'm trying to remake a terminal from the Fallout series, if any of you know what that is.

Basically, the program shows a bunch of options they can choose from, then they have to input a number (1-5) to select which thing they want to view. The program will use an if statement to determine which thing they want to view. For example, if the user inputted one, then it will clear the screen and print a bunch of information, then the user has to input enter, then the screen clears and the options from the beginning are displayed again. This whole thing is inside a while statement, and while the user input is not "C", it will still display all of that other stuff, and when it does become "C", the program will clear everything and the program ends.

I know all of that sounded confusing, but basically the problem is that if the person inputs a number, it doesn't do the clearing thing, it just displays the choices again.

I'll just display the code, so if anyone could tell me what the problem is, that would greatly be appreciated.

```
def confusingFunction():
    from os import system
    userChoice = ""

    while userChoice.upper() != "C":
        print("Choice 1")
        print("Choice 2")
        print("Choice 3")
        print("Choice 4")
        print("Choice 5")
        userChoice = input(">>>")

        if userChoice == 1:
            system('cls')
            print("Stuff")
            print("Stuff")
            print("Stuff")
            input(">>>")
            system('cls')

    system('cls')
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with type conversion. Python takes input as string.
Try the code

`if int(userChoice) == 1:`

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs the entire, actual code, here you go...`

```
locked = False
#Define Function
def accessGranted():
    import time
    from os import system
    userChoice = ""
    while userChoice.upper() != "C":
        print("Welcome to BunkerSoft Corporations(TM) Terminal\nClearance: Overseer Eyes Only\nBy using this terminal, you are acknowledging that you are an authorized user or technician. Unauthorized users must cease reading and log out of this terminal immediately. Violators will be subject to civil and criminal penalties.\n")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("1. [BUNKER 012 OVERSEER INSTRUCTIONS]")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("2. [Overseer Logs]")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("3. [Experiments]")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("4. [Lab]")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("5. [Cache]\n")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        userChoice = input(">>>")
        while userChoice == 1:
            system('cls')
            print("Welcome to BunkerSoft Corporations(TM) 
Terminal\nClearance: Overseer Eyes Only\n")
            print("CONFIDENTIAL CONFIDENTIAL CONFIDENTIAL\nOVERSEER EYES ONLY | VIOLATION BST&A-01001\n")
            print("Bunker 012 is designed to research infectious diseases on various lifeforms, including human beings, with particular attention paid to potential mutations in a climate of heavy radiation, with an eventual hope to discover a cure and immunity to this cancerous .")
        print("Due to long-term exposure to post-nuclear gamma radiation, infected lifeforms have had their brains permenantly damaged, resulting in complete loss of normal reasoning capabilities and higher thought processes, becoming more animalistic, impulsive, and hostile to anything.")
        print("As of the post-nuclear sealment of this bunker, you are aware of the Bunkers two sections. The main section is where a total of 128 Bunker residents can live in for the foreseeable future, and the secret closed off section of the Bunker, with a Bunker door designed not to close properly. This will be where main testing of the effects of gamma radiation will be conducted.")
        print("Clinical trials are a vital part of Bunker 012's mission. Trials will be performed in three stages: Firstly, live specimens from outside the bunker will be held captive to study their neurogical and physical subconcious. Secondly, Bunker residents will be asked to enter the vault for screening, where they will unknowingly be exposed to different diseases and cures for the radiation poisoning via propellant nozzles that the resident should suspect is the cleansing spray. Thirdly, the secret Bunker's connection and barrier to the main vault will be open, exposing all the residents to the radiation poisoning, and using the final created cure to cure and immunize the residents.")
        print("For your safety and for the scientific staff, you and them will be restricted to the hermetically-sealed research area, and under no circumstance will you engage in direct communication with any of the Bunker residents unless instructed otherwise from BunkerSoft HQ. This measure reduces the chance of cross contamination between Bunker staff and residents.")
        print("As a Bunker Overseer, biological and neurogical scientists, and survivor of the nuclear war, you agree that you have been assigned to a task that will bring forth a better future for the last remnants of humanity: to create an ultimate cure to fight the gamma radiation the Chinese communists have plagued us with. Make BunkerSoft proud, Overseer Bridgeman.")
        userChoice=input(">>>")
        system('cls')
system('cls')
return

def hackingMinigame():
    #Import modules
    import random
    import time
    from os import system

    #Declare  Variables
    tryAgain = "Y"
    characters = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
    pwdString = (characters[18], characters[19], characters[14], characters[15])
    pwdStop = ''.join(pwdString)
    pwdString = (characters[10], characters[8], characters[11], characters[11])
    pwdKill = ''.join(pwdString) 
    pwdString = (characters[19], characters[17], characters[8], characters[15])
    pwdTrip = ''.join(pwdString)
    pwdString = (characters[18], characters[7], characters[8], characters[15])
    pwdShip = ''.join(pwdString)
    pwdString = (characters[17], characters[20], characters[11], characters[4])
    pwdRule = ''.join(pwdString)
    pwdString = (characters[6], characters[17], characters[14], characters[22])
    pwdGrow = ''.join(pwdString)
    pwdString = (characters[15], characters[0], characters[18], characters[18])
    pwdPass = ''.join(pwdString)
    pwdString = (characters[22], characters[4], characters[13], characters[19])
    pwdWent = ''.join(pwdString)
    pwdString = (characters[22], characters[8], characters[13], characters[3])
    pwdWind = ''.join(pwdString)
    pwdString = (characters[25], characters[14], characters[13], characters[4])
    pwdZone = ''.join(pwdString)
    passwords = [pwdStop,pwdKill,pwdTrip,pwdShip,pwdRule,pwdGrow,pwdPass,pwdWent,pwdWind,pwdZone]




    while tryAgain.upper() == "Y":
        attempts = 4
        check = ""
        userInput = ""
        correctPassword = random.sample(passwords,1)
        correctPassword = ''.join(correctPassword)
        print("Welcome to BunkerSoft Corporations(TM) Terminal")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("Password Required")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("4 Attempts\n")
        print("0x587C  ;'%@*([}^.']   Ox6030  <_`%[:._^~.$")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("0x588F  ^&'KILL*$(#*   Ox604G  #%^!5>:,>|='")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("0x589H  ,&;|$)![}*/,   Ox605A  GROW|/+&!;^$")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("0x590Y  @{=_*}:*=^_{   Ox6068  -*=],&'%`>_}")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("0x591R  '`<=%,_<?~%?   Ox6073  %`-[{!]{__#<")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("0x592W  >'|>%~\$=,#_   Ox608F  |./$(%;)!;^$")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("0x593N  `.++}[}_TRIP   Ox609A  ,>:$(PASS^$>")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("0x5945  -_%@*(-]%)|!   Ox610S  ~!<`*?(WENT@")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("0x5958  `.*+}[}_){'(   Ox611Y  %@}*-\_`,(:'")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("0x596G  \_'\?*#-%*]{   Ox612K  +%&{*)~+{;[_")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("0x597C  +#-SHIP!>^_[   Ox613L  =!];./#%~~<*")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("0x5981  ;'RULE^%!;,>   Ox614O  #;^WIND)+[|%")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("0x599F  (]=){_~`,_<&   Ox615U  $&%)^'%})!/%")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("0x6006  '>=-`[).$]|]   Ox6160  @}*-\_`,(:',")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("0x601L  ;'%@*([}^[ST   Ox617O  %:<{ZONE~]!#")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("0x602I  OP@*#;,>?[=]   Ox618J  |./$(%!)!;^$")
        print(correctPassword)

        while attempts > 0:
            userInput = input(">>>").upper()



            if len(userInput) != len(correctPassword):
                print("Error")
                continue
            for i in range(4):
                if userInput[i] not in characters:
                    print("Error")
                    continue



            check = ''
            if userInput != correctPassword:
                for i in range(4):
                    if userInput[i] == correctPassword[i]:
                        check += "X"
                attempts = attempts-1
                print("Access Denied")
            elif userInput == correctPassword:
                print("Access Granted")
                time.sleep(1)
                system('cls')
                locked = True
                accessGranted()
                attempts = 0
                continue

            if attempts != 0 and check != "XXXX":
                print("Likeness =", len(check))
            elif attempts == 0 and check != "XXXX":
                print("Init Lockout")




            if attempts == 0:
                tryAgain = input("Reboot? (Y/N)")
                system('cls')
    return
while locked == False:
    hackingMinigame()
```

It's a LOT, I know, and it's extremely confusing, but I'm open to any suggestions as to how this should work..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import subprocess
userChoice = ""

while userChoice.upper() != "C":
    print("Choice 1")
    print("Choice 2")
    print("Choice 3")
    print("Choice 4")
    print("Choice 5")
    userChoice = raw_input(">>>")

    if userChoice == '1':
        subprocess.call('clear')
        print("Stuff")
        print("Stuff")
        print("Stuff")
        userChoice = raw_input(">>>")
        subprocess.call('clear')

subprocess.call('clear')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Python 2.x**

`input` evaluates whatever you entered and returns the result of evaluation.
So, `userChoice` is int when the user input is a number and it's a string when the user input is a string.

You can use `raw_input` to avoid the evaluation.

**Python 3.x**

`input` doesn't evaluate the entered value.